# Image format with Subimages or layers

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, image-formats

Let's say that I have a paint program like adobe illustrator (currently referring to Krita software), and let's say iI made 5 layers and painted a simple stickman. One layer is a transparent canvas, two is two legs, three is body, four hands and five head. All those layers combined made a stickman (that is fine). Now I load this picture into actionscript3. But now lets say that I want to move only legs by 10pixels without moving rest of the body. I won't be able to do this, maximum that I can is move the whole stickman by 10pixel. Is there a format that will save whole image but also will indicate 5 subgroup (subimages, subdata.... call it what you want) like legs, body and others? Goal of this is that sometimes I want to rotate all stickman but sometimes I want to move only specific part like legs. Or the only way is to make 4 pictures of every body part and load them 1 by 1 into as3 and after combine into 1 single stickman?

I hope this picture will help you a little:

[image: https://gyazo.com/ad6de45fdfdfc90b17b49db3c293c13b]

Comment: you can do this with swf, just make it a movieclip symbol with subsymbols added to it - you will be able to access it through their instance names in as3 after loading the swf

Comment: @MartonPallagi . Hmmmmm i like your idea, think is i don't use adobe flash as it trialware, and as license say i can only use it commercialy after i pay for it. That why i have chosen Krita for drawing(basicly same as ilustrator). Ok so solution is good but still 1 problem. Is there other way to makie movie_clip without flash tools, like othere free software or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to save your file in PSD format.
There is a PSD parser in as3 for you: https://github.com/warrenseine/as3-psd-parser/

```
var psdParser :PSDParser = PSDParser.getInstance();
psdParser.parse(file.data); 

var layersLevel :Sprite = new Sprite();
var arr:Array = new Array();

for (var i : Number = 0;i < psdParser.allLayers.length; i++) {
    var psdLayerm :PSDLayer = psdParser.allLayers[i];
    var layerBitmap_bmp :BitmapData = psdLayer.bmp;
    var layerBitmap :Bitmap = new Bitmap(layerBitmap_bmp);
    layerBitmap.x = psdLayer.position.x;
    layerBitmap.y = psdLayer.position.y;
    layerBitmap.filters = psdLayer.filters_arr;
    layersLevel.addChild(layerBitmap);

    arr.push(layerBitmap);
}


// Move legs
arr[0].x += 10;
```